Failing to deploy .war file on weblogic
While trying to deploy a simple .war file on weblogic, the weblogic stops with the below error. Before doing this I had followed the below steps:

Installed JDK
Installed generic Weblogic
started weblogic and deployed a .war file. After Activate changes it was fine, but when I start the deployment the weblogic portal crashed and below error appeared on startWeblogic screen.

Error appears to be due to jdk/jre not connected properly, not sure what I missed or is it something else?


Please copy or type the text into the question. Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

You are not providing much information about the issue. Please read How to Ask. The [edit] the question to add a [mre]. Include which version of the JDK, version of Weblogic, operating system and version, what the war does and the content of the hs_err.pid*.log file. Use [code block] format for code and logs.

did you look at the logfile? It should contain valuable information.

Which WebLogic Server version are you using and which JDK version ?
Your screen shot shows JDK 22 but no WebLogic Server versions support JDK 22.
WLS 12c supports JDK 8 and WLS 14c JDK 8 or 11.

its WLS 14c , ok so i need to remove jdk and downgrade it to 11 ?

Install Oracle JDK 11 and update your domain configuration to use it.
